# SQL query to get a sum of values grouped by another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have this results:

[image]

The query I'm using currently is:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [FundReportLoanDataID]
      ,[SegAmortisation]
      ,frlc.FundReportCategoryId,
      SUM(CurrentLB) AS '% of Fund'
  FROM [dbo].[FundReportLoanData] frld
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[FundReportCategories] frlc
  ON frld.SegAmortisation = frlc.Description
    group by frlc.FundReportCategoryId, frld.SegAmortisation, frld.FundReportLoanDataID, frld.LoanId, frld.CurrentLB
```

As you can see although I'm grouping by FundReportCategoryId, there are multiple results with the same id but I want all of them to be put in one sum result based on the FundReportCategoryId.

What do I need to change in order to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Just remove FundReportLoanDataID from select & group by? is there something more complex here you're not mentioning...

Comment: This is what i have after your advice https://i.gyazo.com/5415081ac5af1d49c2e5fee971568e12.png

Comment: Could you please put the output you expect

Comment: I would like to get the sum of CurrentLB as '% of Fund' based on the FundReportCategoryId. Thanks @j.t.

Comment: When asking questions like this, show use an example of the data and then what you expect.

Comment: Hi @J.t. thanks for your help, as you can see the image I included in the post is showing what I'm getting currently. Now for example I want to group all the amounts for FundReportCategoryId of 34 in one record. Pls let me know if you understand. Thanks

Comment: I meant you should provide a grid showing the results you expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126550/discussion-between-laziale-and-j-t).

Comment: There are three attempts at answering this below (one deleted) and subsequently the question appears to have been abandoned. I thus wonder if this is missing an [mcve] and thus can be put on hold for now.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to sum `CurrentLB` and the same column is added in `Group by` also that is the reason for duplicates. Remove the `frld.CurrentLB` from `Group by`

Also you need to remove `FundReportLoanDataID` from `SELECT` and `group by` becasue the data looks unique for each row.

```
...
group by frld.SegAmortisation, 
         frld.FundReportLoanDataID
```

Removed the `frld.LoanId` also from `Group By` because you are not selecting it that also could be a reason for duplicates

Comment: Same output again.

Comment: @Laziale - check now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the Percent of each FundReportCategoryId.  If so, you can use the window functions

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [FundReportLoanDataID]
      ,[SegAmortisation]
      ,frlc.FundReportCategoryId,
      SUM(CurrentLB)/SUM(CurrentLB) OVER(PARTITION BY frlc.FundReportCategoryId ) AS '% of Fund'
  FROM [dbo].[FundReportLoanData] frld
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[FundReportCategories] frlc
  ON frld.SegAmortisation = frlc.Description
  group by frlc.FundReportCategoryId, frld.SegAmortisation, frld.FundReportLoanDataID, frld.LoanId, frld.CurrentLB
```

Comment: Hi @john Can you please write whole query again, I'm not getting the expected result

Comment: This is what I'm getting Column 'dbo.FundReportLoanData.CurrentLB' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Laziale Updated  Assuming the image is what you want except the last column as a percent

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/4c4fbfec868ef06e43109d58333a0553.png this is what I'm getting now

Comment: As you can see I'm still getting multiple records for the same FundReportCategoryId

Comment: @Laziale The even an image of the desired results would be more helpful and less open to interpretation.

Comment: I want all the CurrentLB amounts to be summarized under one field for each FundReportCategoryId. In the screenshot I provided as you can see there are 15+ records for FundReportCategoryId of 34 and each record has different value. I want to summarize all the values in one record based on the FundReportCategoryId. I can share teamviewer session as well if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 
        [SegAmortisation],
        frlc.FundReportCategoryId,
        SUM(CurrentLB) AS '% of Fund'
    FROM [dbo].[FundReportLoanData] frld
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[FundReportCategories] frlc
        ON frld.SegAmortisation = frlc.Description
    GROUP BY frld.SegAmortisation, frlc.FundReportCategoryId
```

Next time please provide your desired output :)